# D3 enter/exit groups of circles for paths

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I am creating an interface whereby users can generate a multi-series line chart with control over what data sets are graphed.

Which data sets to graph are controlled by check boxes.  On page load, default data sets are graphed, and

```
$('input:checkbox.data-set-control').on('change')
```

the graph is updated to either add or remove requested data sets.

Fiddle: [Multi-series line chart with enter/exit transitions](https://jsfiddle.net/eg3dya9u/14/)

I refactored the code to exclude the d3.json() requests, among a few things, however the general functionality remains the same.

My problem in all this is getting the circles, which represent a series' data points, to properly enter/exit.  On my server, the circles properly update, but do not exit. (For some reason, neither the update nor exit are working in the Fiddle...)

I've read and reread all of Mike's tutorials about D3 update/enter/exit functionality, in addition to looking at every example I can find that even remotely utilizes update/enter/exit for line charts.  I believe my problem is with the selection that I then operate on for the circles, though after hours of tinkering I cannot seem to figure out the proper scope or structure or whatever.

A brief summary of how the chart data is structured:

```
data = [Object, Object, ...]

data[Object] = {
   name: dataSetName,
   data: [Object, Object, ...]
}

data[Object].data = [
   {
      x: val1,
      y: val2,
   }, ...
]
```

Any guidance and direction for understanding update/enter/exit in this case is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

--
Neal B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple issues here:

1.) You aren't handling, the enter/update/exit pattern for your nodeGroup `g` elements.  In particular the exiting `g`s are problematic.

2.) When you select your circles, you are using `selectAll('.circle')`: select everything of **class** circle (which doesn't exist).  What you mean there is `selectAll('circle')`: select everything of **element** circle.  Further, I'd recommend you use classes on both `nodeGroup` and `dataNode`.  It'll cause less problems as you continue to build your graph.

Here it is all fixed up:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  <script data-require="jquery@2.1.4" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    svg {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }
    
    svg .text {
      font-size: 1.2em;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    
    .controls {
      display: block;
      margin-left: 20px;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    
    .line {
      fill: none;
    }
    
    .grid {
      stroke: #eee;
    }
    
    .bar {
      fill: #40779C;
    }
    
    .bar:hover {
      fill: #AD4444;
    }
    
    .barChart .x.axis path {
      stroke: none;
    }
    
    .barChart .text,
    .lineChart .text {
      fill: #fff;
    }
    
    .pieChart .text {
      fill: #666;
    }
    
    .arc path {
      stroke: #fff;
    }
    
    #getData {
      margin-left: 10px;
    }
    
    #weeks {
      margin-left: 10px;
    }
    
    .accordion-title {
      margin: 3px 0;
    }
    
    .overlay {
      fill: none;
      stroke: none;
    }
    
    .dataNode {
      fill: #eee;
      stroke: #666;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          Data sets
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" class="data-set-control" checked="" />
              <span>dataSet1</span>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" class="data-set-control" checked="" />
              <span>dataSet2</span>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" class="data-set-control" checked="" />
              <span>dataSet3</span>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" class="data-set-control" />
              <span>dataSet4</span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="row">
    <div id="chartContainer"></div>
  </div>
  <script>
    dataSet1 = {
      name: 'dataSet1',
      data: [{
        x: 0,
        y: 19
      }, {
        x: 1,
        y: 16
      }, {
        x: 2,
        y: 21
      }, {
        x: 3,
        y: 24
      }, {
        x: 4,
        y: 19
      }, {
        x: 5,
        y: 18
      }, {
        x: 6,
        y: 22
      }]
    }

    dataSet2 = {
      name: 'dataSet2',
      data: [{
        x: 0,
        y: 26
      }, {
        x: 1,
        y: 23
      }, {
        x: 2,
        y: 29
      }, {
        x: 3,
        y: 34
      }, {
        x: 4,
        y: 27
      }, {
        x: 5,
        y: 28
      }, {
        x: 6,
        y: 33
      }]
    };
    dataSet3 = {
      name: 'dataSet3',
      data: [{
        x: 0,
        y: 45
      }, {
        x: 1,
        y: 51
      }, {
        x: 2,
        y: 42
      }, {
        x: 3,
        y: 47
      }, {
        x: 4,
        y: 54
      }, {
        x: 5,
        y: 57
      }, {
        x: 6,
        y: 49
      }]
    };
    dataSet4 = {
      name: 'dataSet4',
      data: [{
        x: 0,
        y: 80
      }, {
        x: 1,
        y: 69
      }, {
        x: 2,
        y: 81
      }, {
        x: 3,
        y: 84
      }, {
        x: 4,
        y: 78
      }, {
        x: 5,
        y: 83
      }, {
        x: 6,
        y: 85
      }]
    };
    // coerce json strings to integers
    function mapData(data) {
      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.data.forEach(function(v) {
          v.y = (v.y) ? +v.y : null;
        });
      });
      return data;
    }
    // get requested data sets for json request
    function getDataSets() {
      // loop through checked boxes for requested data sets
      dataSets = [];
      var c = 0;
      $('input:checkbox.data-set-control').each(function(i) {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
          var name = $(this).siblings('span').html();
          var val = $(this).val();
          if (name == 'dataSet1') {
            dataSets[c] = dataSet1;
            c++;
          }
          if (name == 'dataSet2') {
            dataSets[c] = dataSet2;
            c++
          }
          if (name == 'dataSet3') {
            dataSets[c] = dataSet3;
            c++;
          }
          if (name == 'dataSet4') {
            dataSets[c] = dataSet4;
            c++;
          }
        }
      });
      return dataSets;
    }
    // svg margins
    var margin = {
      top: 20,
      right: 30,
      bottom: 30,
      left: 40
    };
    // svg dimensions
    totalW = 900;
    totalH = 400;

    var width = totalW - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = totalH - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    var radius = 3;

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([0, width], .1);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([height, 0]);

    var svg = d3.select('#chartContainer').append('svg')
      .attr('class', 'lineChart')
      .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

    var color = d3.scale.category10();

    var line = d3.svg.line()
      .defined(function(d) {
        return d.y != null;
      })
      .interpolate('cardinal')
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.x);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.y);
      });


    function render() {
      /*
      var ajax = JSON.stringify( getDataSets() );
      var url = '../scripts/d3-data.php?ajax='+ajax;
      d3.json(url, function (data) { */
      // json normally returns an array of objects commensurate
      // to the number of checked boxes representing data sets

      // manually set data for fiddle
      data = getDataSets();
      // global width/height variables are lost through json request
      totalW = 900;
      totalH = 400;
      var width = totalW - margin.left - margin.right;
      var height = totalH - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      // coerce json to integers
      d3Data = mapData(data);

      color.domain(d3Data.map(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      }));

      x.domain([
        0,
        d3.max(d3Data, function(d) {
          return d3.max(d.data, function(v) {
            return v.x;
          });
        })
      ]);
      y.domain([
        0,
        d3.max(d3Data, function(d) {
          return d3.max(d.data, function(v) {
            return v.y + 10;
          });
        })
      ]);

      var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient('bottom');

      var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient('left');

      // check if y axis exists
      if (svg.selectAll(".y.axis")[0].length < 1) {
        // does not, append to svg
        svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis);
      } else {
        // does, so transition any domain change(s)
        var updateY = svg.selectAll(".y.axis");
        updateY.transition().duration(500).call(yAxis);
      }

      // x axis never changes so only append if doesn't exist
      if (svg.selectAll('.x.axis')[0].length < 1) {
        svg.append('g')
          .attr('class', 'x axis')
          .call(xAxis)
          .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')');
      }

      // only add horizontal grid if doesn't exist
      if (svg.selectAll('.grid')[0].length < 1) {
        // add horizontal lines for readability
        svg.append('g')
          .attr('class', 'grid')
          .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
            .orient('left')
            .tickSize(-(width), 0, 0)
            .tickValues(function(d, i) {
              var tickVals = [];
              var max = d3.max(d3Data, function(d) {
                return d3.max(d.data, function(v) {
                  return +v.y;
                });
              });
              for (i = 10; i < (max + 10); i += 10) {
                tickVals.push(i);
              }
              return tickVals;
            })
            .tickFormat('')
          );
      }

      var path = svg.selectAll('.line')
        .data(d3Data)
        .attr('class', 'line');

      path.transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attr('d', function(d) {
          return line(d.data);
        })
        .style('stroke', function(d) {
          return color(d.name);
        });

      path.enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('class', 'line')
        .attr('d', function(d) {
          return line(d.data);
        })
        .style('stroke', function(d) {
          return color(d.name);
        });

      path.exit().remove();

      var nodeGroup = svg.selectAll('.nodeGroup')
        .data(d3Data, function(d){
          return d.name;
        });
        
      nodeGroup.exit().remove();
        
      nodeGroup  
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'nodeGroup');

      var circles = nodeGroup.selectAll('.dataNode')
        .data(function(d) {
          return d.data;
        });

      circles.enter()
        .append('circle')
        .style('opacity', 0)
        .attr('class', 'dataNode')
        .attr('r', function(d) {
          return d.y == null ? 0 : radius;
        });

      circles.exit().remove();

      circles
        .attr('cx', function(d) {
          return x(d.x);
        })
        .attr('cy', function(d) {
          return y(d.y);
        })
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .delay(300)
        .style('opacity', 1);

      //});
    }

    render();

    $(function() {

      $('input:checkbox.data-set-control').on('change', function() {
        var type;
        $('.btn-group button.btn').each(function() {
          if ($(this).hasClass('active')) type = $(this).html().toLowerCase();
        });
        render();
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That is a beautiful thing.  After hours of hitting my head against the monitor, I simply could not wrap my head around what I figured was a very easy fix.  Thank you for the clarification and updated code!